# Animate div on click and make full width jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to create a interaction and it should work like following:

1. When clicked on first div - It should animate to right cover other div
2. When clicked on second div - it should animate to left and right
3. When clicked on third div - it should animate left

It seems to be working as expected but the animation is not as expected, its jumping, how do I make it smooth?

Here is the [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jhwfg4aa/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $(".column").height(winh);
  
  $(".first-col").click(function(){
   $(".first-col").animate({width:winw, left:0, zIndex:2}, 3000);
  });
  
  $(".second-col").click(function(){
   $(".second-col").animate({width:winw, left:0, right:0, zIndex:2}, 2000);
  });
  $(".third-col").click(function(){
   $(".third-col").animate({width:winw, left:0, zIndex:2}, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
}
.wrapper > .column {
 width: 33.3333%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
  text-align:center;
}
.first-col {
 background: #cdcdcd;
 left: 0;
}
.second-col {
 background: #dadada;
 left: 33.3333%;
}
.third-col {
 background: #bababa;
 left: 66.6666%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="column first-col">
  <h1>Title Here</h1>
  <p>content here</p>
 </div>
 <div class="column second-col">
  <h1>Title Here</h1>
  <p>content here</p>
 </div>
 <div class="column third-col">
  <h1>Title Here</h1>
  <p>content here</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working by setting the z-index of the div to 2 before you trigger the animation:

```
$(".first-col").css('z-index', '2');
$(".first-col").animate({width:winw, left:0}, 3000);
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhwfg4aa/2/) to see a working example.

Hope this helps.